# dataweave 1.0 to 2.0 migration in mule

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

Trying to convert the below **dataweave from 1.0 to 2.0**, but everything I've tried gives the following errors like

> SkipNullon shows error
>
> Usage of Namespacing is not accepted,
>
> @PostalCode[0..4] is not valid and
>
> can't access the value inside insuredInfo using insuredPrimaryAddr.

**Dataweave 1.0:**

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere"
%var insuredInfo = payload.DTOApplication.DTOInsured
%var insuredPrimaryAddr = insuredInfo.*PartyInfo[?($.@PartyTypeCd == "InsuredParty")].*Addr[?($.@AddrTypeCd == "InsuredPrimaryBusAddr")][0]
%namespace ns0 http://decisionresearch.com/RateMaker
---
ns0#rate:{
    ns0#code:insuredPrimaryAddr,
    ns0#ZipCode: payload..Addr[?($.@AddrTypeCd == "InsuredPrimaryBusAddr")][0].@PostalCode[0..4] default ""
}
```

I tried **Dataweave 2.0:**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere"
var insuredInfo = payload.DTOApplication.DTOInsured
var insuredPrimaryAddr = insuredInfo.*PartyInfo[?($.@PartyTypeCd == "InsuredParty")].*Addr[?($.@AddrTypeCd == "InsuredPrimaryBusAddr")][0]
namespace ns0 http://decisionresearch.com/RateMaker
---
ns0#rate:{
    ns0#code:insuredPrimaryAddr,
    ns0#ZipCode: payload..Addr[?($.@AddrTypeCd == "InsuredPrimaryBusAddr")][0].@PostalCode[0..4] default ""
}
```

payload : https://github.com/Manikandan99/rate-dtostep/blob/master/response.xml

Any ideas please on how to write the same in dataweave 2.0?

Comment: Use ns instead of namespace keyword to declare a namespace in DW 2.0. As well use 'to' instead of '..' .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In dataweave 2.0 we use `to` operator for array indexing.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere"
var insuredInfo = payload.DTOApplication.DTOInsured
var insuredPrimaryAddr = insuredInfo.*PartyInfo[?($.@PartyTypeCd == "InsuredParty")].*Addr[?($.@AddrTypeCd == "InsuredPrimaryBusAddr")][0]
ns ns0 http://decisionresearch.com/RateMaker
---
ns0#rate:{
    ns0#code:insuredPrimaryAddr,
    ns0#ZipCode: payload..Addr[?($.@AddrTypeCd == "InsuredPrimaryBusAddr")][0].@PostalCode[0 to 4] default ""
}
```

Output

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<ns0:rate xmlns:ns0="http://decisionresearch.com/RateMaker">
  <ns0:ZipCode>80003</ns0:ZipCode>
</ns0:rate>
```